# Android camara parameters getZoomRatio() values not as expected

Tags: android, camera, zooming, augmented-reality

if i get a list of zoom ratios with: parameters.getZoomRatios(), values returned are 100,114...200 (corresponeding to 1x 1.14x ...2.0x zoom), but in the camera preview at 200 (2x zoom), the picture appears zoomed much more then 2x.  in sample images, show a 6cm fov at 1x and 2.5cm at 2x zoom... I was expecting 3.0cm at 2x.

[image: 6 cm at 1x (100) zoom]
[image: 2.5 cm at 2x (200) zoom]

Is there another way i should be interpreting these values?...Anyone else see this?   or is this device/version specific, or should i be multiplying by some constant or other value (focal length)?  i'm trying to match my camera view to rendered view for my app, and as i zoom, this is messing up the matching.

code is standard here:

```
public void setZoom(int pZoom)
{
    final Camera.Parameters p = this.mCamera.getParameters();
    if (p.isZoomSupported())
    {
        p.setZoom(pZoom);
        this.mCamera.setParameters(p);

    }


}

    public int getZoom( android.hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        int zoom = 100;

        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        if (p.isZoomSupported())
        {
            final List<Integer> zoomRatios = p.getZoomRatios();
            final int zoomIndex = p.getZoom();
            if (zoomIndex < zoomRatios.size())
            {
                zoom = zoomRatios.get(zoomIndex);
            }   
            //Log.d("zoom","ix:" + zoomIndex + " z:"+zoom);         

        }               
        return zoom;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling the function "camera.getParameters().getZoomRatios()" seems to be the safest way to get to the camera's zoom ratios. Well, it is so, but -as far as I know- it doesn't behave in the same way on each android device.

I've tested the zoom ratios on different devices: when called getZoomRatios() on Asus, it returned this:
[100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450,
 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800].
With these zoom ratios, if you tested 6.0cm at 1X zoom it would have resulted 3.0cm at 2X zoom.

However, Samsung returned me this list:
[100, 102, 104, 109, 111, 113, 119, 121, 124, 131, 134, 138, 146, 150, 155, 
159, 165, 170, 182, 189, 200, 213, 222, 232, 243, 255, 283, 300, 319, 364, 400]. 
These values are a little bit weird, because while testing 6.0cm at 1X zoom, it would have failed to result the expected 3.0cm at 2X zoom. When I verified the zoom factors on the device's standard camera application, I realized that the zoom ratios must be equidistant. I generated another list of zoom ratios instead, with equidistant values: [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400].

For example, if I want to set the zoom to 2X, I'll have "parameters.setZoom(20)" (see the original Samsung list), which is, in fact, a mistake, because I will not have the expected 2X zoom, but 3X zoom (see the generated list).

If your zoomRatios list is not to be trusted, try to generate your own zoomRatios list calculating the distance between two successive zoom ratios assuming that the smallest(1X) and the greatest zoom values are correctly returned. By the way, the size of the zoom ratios list is also the correct one, so for calculating the difference between two consecutive zoom ratio values you can use the formula: (greatestZoomRatio - smallestZoomRatio) / numberOfZoomRatioElements.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled upon this issue when trying to fix an equivalent zoom level for different phone models. The ratios seemed promising but I gave up using them because it was too inconsistent.

As King Arthur, I also realised the values should have been equidistant, only the last value sometimes didn't reflect the actual zoom factor. Here's for example the ratios of my Samsung S4:
[100, 102, 104, 107, 109, 112, 114, 117, 120, 123, 125, 128, 131, 135, 138, 141, 144, 148, 151, 155, 158, 162, 166, 170, 174, 178, 182, 186, 190, 195, 200]
It is misguiding because the phone has a 4x zoom but the list doesn't end with 400!

I don't see the logic, so in the end I just gave up.
I'd be very interested if someone can provide an explanation.
Cheers